# Adding apostrophes around values from array / foreach to insert into database

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am working on my own script (personal use, not public so no security needed whatsoever) for learning purposes. I am using the code posted below, to try and insert multiple values into the database, so I can use that function for multiple forms. There is only one problem:

```
VALUES ('', $vals)";
```

Everything works, but the `$vals` are being used like this: test1, test2, test3 and so on. But I need it to be like this: 'test1', 'test2', 'test3' and so on. But I cannot figure out how to add those ' quotes around the values that need to be inserted into the database. I have tried using explode, but I cannot get it to work. Does anyone know how to add those apostrophes or is there another, better/easier way to do this perhaps?

```
public function postForm($table, $formValues)
{
    foreach ($formValues as $key => $value)
    {
        $formKeys[] = $key;
        $vals = implode(", ", $formValues);
        $keys = implode(", ", $formKeys);
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table (id, $keys) VALUES ('', $vals)";
    $result = $this->mysqli->query($sql);
}
```

Comment: I've actually now fixed it using a simple string replace... Figures.. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 0):

This

```
$vals = "'".implode("',' ", $formValues)."'";
```

From [PHP.net documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php#90134)

Comment: Tried it but doesn't work. I have used: $vals  = "'" . str_replace(array("'", ","), array("\\'", "','"), $vals) . "'";

Answer (score 0):

For me, it works on this form:

```
$fee_desc = $_POST['description'];

foreach($fee_desc as $key => $value)
{
    $vals = implode(", ", $fee_desc);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO test (vlera) VALUES ('$vals')";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
```